# Excel - How to remove similar cells within the same column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting, lookup

I have a problem on Excel 2010.

I have a column which lists the names of manufacturers', like so:

Manufacturer
Company 1 Ltd
Company 2 Ltd
Company 3 Ltd

My problem is when there's a spelling mistake in the manufacturer's name or it's missing the ltd or adds a "Co" between the company name and ltd.

Is there a way that I can flag similar text and then somehow replace one with the other?

I thought about conditional formatting and fuzzy lookup but the cells are similar and not duplicates and fuzzy lookup requires 2 columns.

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: If the companies names are already familiar and known to you, why don't you do the cell as drop-down list.

Comment: Because I have half a million rows :/

Comment: How exactly you've tried fuzzy lookup? Why adding a new column is an issue for you? Your task isn't a simple one, probably you won't get a quick solution.

Comment: How about sorting by CompanyName and then perhaps using a Countif to catch when the value changes

Comment: Step 1,  copy the manufacturer column to another sheet and dedupe.  This gives the each unique name.  If the total list is manageable then for each flawed name  USe Ctlr-h on the original sheet, list the flawed name and what you want it replaced with. Check a  couple of entries then use replace all to change every one.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in 2 ways.

1. By using a special add-in, free for the first 15 days: our [Fuzzy Duplicate Finder](https://www.ablebits.com/excel-find-similar/index.php) is specially designed for this task – find similar (fuzzy) matches and correct typos and misprints.
2. By using formulas – free but time-consuming way:

2.1. Copy the source column to an empty sheet, and name it "`Original Name`".

2.2. Remove duplicates.

2.3 Copy the duplicate-free column and paste it nearby, name it "`Correct Name`".

2.4 Sort the "Correct Name" column alphabetically from A to Z.

2.5 Find all typos in the "Correct Name" column (manually or using Fuzzy Duplicate Finder) and correct them. It will be your Lookup table.

2.6 On the original sheet, create a helper column, and then use the Index/Match formula to search in the Original Name column, and return values from the Correct Name column. If a value is not found, return something like "Not found" or "To be added to db". For example:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[#All],MATCH(A2,Table2[[#All],[Original Name]],0),2),"Not Found")`

For more information, please see [INDEX & MATCH functions in Excel - a better alternative to VLOOKUP](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/)